# Any way to customize/limit/set Microsoft Remote Desktop Licensing service port?

Tags: networking, port, windows-server-2016, rds, microsoft

Recently I had a weird problem on one of the Windows Server 2016 servers where Microsoft Remote Desktop Licensing service / TermServLicensing occupied port 1541 & prevented another critical 3rd party service from starting.

Is there a way to customize/limit/set the port of TermServLicensing service to a particular port to prevent that situation from happening once again?

I wasn't able to find any info here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16164.rds-2012-which-ports-are-used-during-deployment.aspx#Remote_Desktop_Licensing_Server

Thanks!

Comment: Why not reconfigure or move the 3rd party service? trying to muck around with the TS Licensing service is just asking for pain.

Comment: If it's that random, then there's no guarantee that ts licensing service won't try to occupy any other important port, right?

Comment: My reading of the linked document says that by default only ports above 49152 should be selected, unless perhaps the rules changed again in Server 2016.  Do you have a registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Rpc\Internet` and if so what values does it contain?

Comment: I didn't have any, but creating some helped: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/154596/how-to-configure-rpc-dynamic-port-allocation-to-work-with-firewalls